# I want to change text of uilabel created at runtime

Tags: iphone, xcode

**Please I want change text of any lbl** I create it in for loop in click method
such as i want change text of the second lbl.
If any way to access uilabel by tag value.

```
for(int i=1,i<5,i++){
UILabel *lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithframe:GCrectMake(0,0,50,50)];
lbl.tag=i;
lbl.text=@"Quan:0";
[self.view addSubview:lbl];
}
-(void)click:(id)sender{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You just call and it will return your label.

```
UILabel *lbl = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:(int)];
```

Comment: thanx Ryan, but when i write this code i get error :            UILabel *lbl = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];                lbl.text=@"aaa";

Comment: when i press button that contain click method my project closed

Comment: because run stops in this step: lbl.text=@"aaa";